# Finding a coefficient in probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm trying to do an assignment from my text atm, but in this specific assignment, I have no idea where to even start. The problem goes as follows:

Let X and Y be random variables with a combined distribution:
$f_\alpha (x,y)=k(\alpha)e^{-|x-y|/\alpha}$ if $0\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq y \leq 1$ and $f(x,y)=0$ elsewhere.

Determine $\rho_{XY}(\alpha)$.

I haven't been able to find any tips within the text so am basically pulling my hair out atm. I hope some of you can help.

Comment: What are causing you trouble? The definition of $\rho_{XY}$ can be found here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient You just need to solve a couple of integrals.

Comment: Well, I can work it down to: 
$\frac{\int \int xyf(x,y)dxdy - E[x]E[y]}{\sqrt{E[x^2]-E[x]^2}\sqrt{E[y^2]-E[y]^2}}$.
But at that point you'll need to know what $k(\alpha)$ is and I don't know how to calculate $E[x]$ with a probability density function of the form $f(x,y)$.

Comment: $E[x] = \int\int x f(x,y) dx dy$ of course. $k(\alpha)$ is just a normalization constant and can be calculated considering that  $\int\int f(x,y) = 1$ must hold. You have everything you need now.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of $ \rho_{XY} $ is:

$ \rho_{XY} = \frac{\sigma_{XY}}{\sigma_{X}\sigma_{Y}} $

**1) Find $ \sigma_{XY} $**

$ \sigma_{XY} = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y) $

**2) Find $ \sigma_{X} $**

$ \sigma_{X} = \sqrt{E(X^2) - (E(X))^2} $

**3) Find $ \sigma_{Y} $**

$ \sigma_{Y} = \sqrt{E(Y^2) - (E(Y))^2} $

As you can see from these equations, you need to find $ E(X) $, $ E(Y) $, and $ E(XY) $.

$ E(X) = \int_{0}^{1} xf_X(x) dx = \int_{0}^{1} x \big[ \int_{0}^{1} f_{XY}(x,y) dy \big] dx = \int_{0}^{1} x \big[ \int_{0}^{1} \kappa(\alpha) e^{-|x-y|/\alpha} dy \big] dx $

$ = \kappa(\alpha)\alpha \big[ \alpha(e^{-1/a} - 1) + 1 \big] $

$ E(Y) = \int_{0}^{1} yf_Y(y) dy = \int_{0}^{1} y \big[ \int_{0}^{1} f_{XY}(x,y) dx \big] dy = \int_{0}^{1} y \big[ \int_{0}^{1} \kappa(\alpha) e^{-|x-y|/\alpha} dx \big] dy = \kappa(\alpha) \alpha \big[ \alpha(e^{-1/\alpha} - 1) + 1 \big] $

Finally, you can find $ E(XY) $:

$ E(XY) = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} xyf_{XY}(x,y) dy dx
= \int_{0}^{1} x \big[ \int_{0}^{1} y \kappa(\alpha) e^{-|x-y|/\alpha} dy \big] dx $

Now all you need to do is substitute these values into the equations for $ \sigma_{X} $, $ \sigma_{Y} $, and $ \sigma_{XY} $. Once you have these quantities, you can easily calculate $ \rho_{XY} $.

**Note**

The value of $ \kappa(\alpha) $ can be found by recognizing that the following equalities are always true: $ \int_{0}^{1} f_X(x)dx = 1 $, $ \int_{0}^{1} f_{Y}(y)dx = 1 $, and $ \int_{0}^{1} f_{XY}(x,y)dx = 1 $. For instance:

$ \int_{0}^{1} f_X(x) dx = \int_{0}^{1} \big[ \int_{0}^{1} f_{XY}(x,y) dy \big] dx = \int_{0}^{1} f_X(x) dx = \int_{0}^{1} \big[ \int_{0}^{1} \kappa(\alpha) e^{-|x-y|/\alpha} dy \big] dx $

$ = \kappa(\alpha) \alpha \int_{0}^{1} \big[ 2 - e^{-x/2} - e^{-(x-1)/2} \big] dx = \kappa(\alpha) \alpha \times 2 \big[ \alpha (e^{-1/\alpha} - 1) + 1 \big] $

Since $ \int_{0}^{1} f_X(x) dx = 1 $,then we get:

$$ \kappa(\alpha) = \frac{1}{2 \alpha \big[ \alpha (e^{-1/\alpha} - 1) + 1 \big]}  $$